# 20.10 => 21.04 update broke Gstreamer's plugins? (RTSP streams over VLC won't work, while i.e. mplayer plays them OK)

Tags: video, vlc, streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

After updating to 21.04 (hirsute), my VLC broke as for the RTSP stream playback functionality. I suspect this to be related to my gstreamer plug-ins breaking down during the install. Running the RTSP stream with `mplayer` from command line works fine when VLC doesn't. The error message from VLC is: `satip stream error: Failed to setup RTSP session`

I've had to temporarily throw these plug-ins out of the GST plugin path for `gst-inspect-1.0` to pass:

```
libgstnrtp.so
libgstnvcodec.so
libgstrtpmanagerbad.so
libgstrtpmanager.so
libgstrtponvif.so
libgstrtp.so
libgstsrtp.so
```

When I still had 20.10, I started to have some weird issues with gstreamer and I had to set the `GST_PLUGINS_PATH` variable to point to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0`; if I stick those abovementioned .so's over to that directory, I get the following greeting:

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 20:43:53.798: cannot register existing type 'GstRtpSrc'

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 20:43:53.798: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GLib-CRITICAL **: 20:43:53.798: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:43:53.798: gst_element_register: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 20:43:53.798: cannot register existing type 'GstRtpSink'

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 20:43:53.798: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GLib-CRITICAL **: 20:43:53.798: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 20:43:53.798: gst_element_register: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT)' failed
DtsGetHWFeatures: Create File Failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 20:43:54.960: specified class size for type 'GstNvH264Dec' is smaller than the parent type's 'GstH264Decoder' class size

(gst-plugin-scanner:21627): GLib-CRITICAL **: 20:43:54.960: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
```

So, in other words, the update broke at least the references for Gstreamer's RTSP plugins, and upon googling it up, it would seem that the abovementioned error usually has something to do with multiple versions of Gstreamer overlapping for some reason -- i.e. for `libgstrtp.so`, it exists in three(!) different locations:

```
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtp.so
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtp.so
```

All help kindly appreciated in untangling this mess. If someone can point out what *should* be the default directory for gst-plugins, maybe I can work from that.